# Linking Python into my C++ code on windows - linker error

Tags: python, c++, windows, linker

I have an error trying to link python into my C++ code.

This is the error line I am getting:

```
C:\Python27\libs/libpython27.a(dmmes00855.o):(.idata$7+0x0): undefined reference to `_head_C__build27_cpython_PCBuild_libpython27_a'

collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

For background, here is minimal case:

```
#include <Python.h>

int main()
{
    Py_Initialize();
}
```

I am using scons to build:

```
import os
env = Environment(ENV = os.environ)
env.Append(CPPPATH = "C:/Python27/include/")
env.Append(LIBPATH = "C:/Python27/libs/")
env.Append(LIBS = "python27")
env.Program("test", "test.cpp")
```

It generates the following commands:

```
g++ -o test.o -c -IC:\Python27\include test.cpp
g++ -o test.exe test.o -LC:\Python27\libs -lpython27
```

Compiler is the mingw that I have as part of my Qt download.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*No problems with `g++` commands.* Apparently, this is a *bug*.

A bugfix release `2.7.10` is currently available. First of all Upgrade to `2.7.10`

Then you need to create `libpython27.a` with

```
gendef.exe python27.dll
```

and

```
dlltool.exe --dllname python27.dll --def python27.def --output-lib libpython27.a
```

and place it in `C:\Python27\libs`

Now compiling with MinGW will work fine.